# Merge interval with merge distance in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, merge, intervals

Given a list of intervals [start, end] I have to merge them based on a specified merge distance. The intervals are arriving in a particular order, and as they arrive it should merge them according to the specified merge distance as each interval is received. Some of these intervals will be removed  (in the arrival stream they will be marked as removed) – in that situation I've to treat the original interval as if it never existed. Example:

Merge distance is 7 – in the following example the input is arriving in order

[image: Output]

I've tried the following algorithm to merge them but my Output isn't coming like the above example. Can somebody assists me, what I'm missing here!

Here is my code.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var intervals = new List<Interval>
            {
                new Interval
                {
                    start = 1,
                    end = 20
                },
                new Interval
                {
                    start = 55,
                    end = 58
                },
                new Interval
                {
                    start = 60,
                    end = 89
                },
                new Interval
                {
                    start = 15,
                    end = 31
                },
                new Interval
                {
                    start = 10,
                    end = 15
                },
                new Interval
                {
                    start = 1,
                    end = 20
                }
            };

            var mergedIntervals = Merge(intervals, 7);

            foreach (var item in mergedIntervals)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"[{item.start}, {item.end}]");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static List<Interval> Merge(List<Interval> intervals, int mergeDistance)
        {
            var result = new List<Interval>();

            for (int i = 0; i < intervals.Count; i++)
            {
                var newInterval = new Interval(intervals[i].start, intervals[i].end);
                //while (i < intervals.Count - 1 && newInterval.end >= intervals[i + 1].start)
                while (i < intervals.Count - 1 && newInterval.end <= mergeDistance) //  intervals[i + 1].start)
                {
                    newInterval.end = Math.Max(newInterval.end, intervals[i + 1].end);
                    i++;
                }

                result.Add(newInterval);
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

```
 

public class Interval
    {
        public int start { get; set; }
        public int end { get; set; }

        public Interval()
        {

        }

        public Interval(int start, int end)
        {
            this.start = start;
            this.end = end;
        }
    }
```

Comment: For the intervals `[[1,4], [10, 15], [5, 9]]`, and a merge distance of 5, should the interval that came last (`[5, 9]`) merge with `[1,4]` or `[5, 9]` or both?

Comment: if you're considering the merge distance 5 then here is an example:
Given two intervals [1,5] and [10,15] and a merge distance of 5, the two intervals overlap across this merge distance allowing them to be merged to a new interval of [1,15].
Similarly given two intervals [1,5] and [11,15] and a merge distance of 5, you cannot merge these two intervals since they do not overlap across the merge distance

Comment: You did not answer my question. What if there are three intervals: `[1,4]` and `[10, 15]` comes first, then comes `[5, 9]`, and the merge range is 5? Will the output be `[[1, 9], [10, 15]]`, or `[[1,4], [5, 15]]` or `[1, 15]`?

Comment: we can sort it by arrival time and then we can merge it according to distance.

Comment: Do you mean "sort by the _start_ of each interval"? That just throws the whole "comes in a particular order" detail out of the window. Does the order not matter at all?

Comment: Here is the actual statement: 
The input to your program should be a file and a merge interval. The file should have the following format: Arrival time, Start, End, Action – you can assume the file is sorted by arrival time.

Comment: Please, **answer my question** in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64191619/merge-interval-with-merge-distance-in-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment113511969_64191619). Which of the output is expected? Voted to close as needs more details.

Comment: with merge distance 5 it would be [[1,4], [5, 15]]

Comment: And why? There is currently no requirement in your question that would exclude the other possibilities.

Comment: @KlausGütter please elaborate on the other possibilities?

Comment: I refer to the comment above by @Sweeper

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this code, working demo code [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/svipDW)

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var intervals = new List<Interval>
            {
                new Interval
                {
                    start = 1,
                    end = 20,
                    isAdded = true
                },
                new Interval
                {
                    start = 55,
                    end = 58,
                    isAdded = true
                },
                new Interval
                {
                    start = 60,
                    end = 89,
                    isAdded = true
                },
                new Interval
                {
                    start = 15,
                    end = 31,
                    isAdded = true
                },
                new Interval
                {
                    start = 10,
                    end = 15,
                    isAdded = true
                },
                new Interval
                {
                    start = 1,
                    end = 20,
                    isAdded = false
                }
            };

            var mergedIntervals = Merge(intervals, 7);

            foreach (var item in mergedIntervals)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"[{item.start}, {item.end}]");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static List<Interval> Merge(List<Interval> intervals, int mergeDistance)
        {
            var result = new List<IntervalGroup>();
            var group = new IntervalGroup();
            foreach (var item in intervals)
            {
                group = result.Where(c => c.Groups.Any(g =>
                Math.Abs(g.end - item.start) <= mergeDistance ||
                Math.Abs(g.end - item.end) <= mergeDistance)).FirstOrDefault();
                if (group != null && item.isAdded)
                {
                    group.Groups.Add(item);
                }
                else if(item.isAdded)
                {
                    group = new IntervalGroup();
                    group.Groups = new List<Interval>();
                    result.Add(group);
                    group.Groups.Add(item);
                }
                else if(item.isAdded == false)
                {
                    group.Groups.Remove(group.Groups.Where(c => c.start == item.start && c.end == item.end).First());
                }
            }

            var finalResult = result.Select(s => new Interval { start = s.Groups.Min(min => min.start), end = s.Groups.Max(min => min.end) });
            return finalResult.ToList();
        }
    }

    public class Interval
    {
        public int start { get; set; }
        public int end { get; set; }

        public bool isAdded { get; set; }

        public Interval()
        {

        }

        public Interval(int start, int end, bool isAdded)
        {
            this.start = start;
            this.end = end;
            this.isAdded = isAdded;
        }
    }

    public class IntervalGroup
    {
        public List<Interval> Groups { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for code, but it's giving me Fatal Error: execution time limit was exceeded on the demo. However, the action column we need to show in output either the next or incoming interval is added or removed.

Comment: You are welcome! Try it in your local machine it might online site error. Would you pls explain it in a bit detail?

Comment: The input to your program should be a file and a merge interval. The file should have the following format: Arrival time, Start, End, Action – you can assume the file is sorted by arrival time. The Action column is a string value which is either “ADDED” or “REMOVED” . Removed means that the original interval was removed from the input stream. In the example above, when Removed is called on the action in sequence 6, it is actually removing the interval that showed up in sequence

Answer (score 1):

When a problem is beyond your grasp, it is very helpful to break it up into smaller pieces and code the bits that you do understand. Here's how I break it down, step by step.

First, I think it would be convenient to be able to check the length of an interval, so let's add a property.

```
class Interval
{
    /* Prior code */

    public int Length => this.end - this.start;
```

Now let's write a method that merges two intervals:

```
class Interval
{
    /* Prior code */

    static public Interval Merge(Interval a, Interval b )
    {
        return new Interval(Math.Min(a.start, b.start), Math.Max(a.end, b.end));
    }
```

Now we need to write the code that decides if two intervals are capable of being merged. The prototype could look like this:

```
static public bool CanMerge(Interval a, Interval b, int mergeDistance)
```

What logic do we need inside? Well, we could check for overlaps and check the merge distance from both ends, but I know a shortcut. Given a merge A + B = C, the merge is allowed if and only if the length of C is less than or equal to the sum of A + B + the merge distance. So we can write this:

```
class Interval
{
    /* Prior code */

    static public bool CanMerge(Interval a, Interval b, int mergeDistance)
    {
        var merged = Merge(a,b);
        var canMerge = merged.Length <= a.Length + b.Length + mergeDistance;

        return canMerge;
    }
```

From there you can add to a list by checking for mergeable items. Note that recursion is required because the act of merging an interval could result in another interval becoming mergeable.

```
void AddToList(List<Interval> list, Interval newInterval, int mergeDistance)
{
    var target = list.FirstOrDefault( x => Interval.CanMerge(x, newInterval, mergeDistance) );
    if (target == null)
    {
        list.Add(newInterval);
        return;
    }
    list.Remove(target);
    AddToList(list, Interval.Merge(target, newInterval), mergeDistance);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @John Wu, but how I can return the list for output? as the AddToList method is recursive and also not returning any list. Can you please update the Main function?

Comment: The method will modify the list that is being passed in.